# trying to get the jquery Datepicker to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I can't seem to get this working altho it is all on the website. I am not any good at js so that doesn't help either to be honest.

so I have basically done exactly the same as what they have on their website but just doesn't seem to function.

```
Signup open:<br><input type="text" name="reg_start" class="datepicker" value=""/><br>
Signup closed:<br><input type="text" name="reg_end" class="datepicker" value=""/><br>
```

This is there code what is the same as mine

```
<script language="javascript" src="protoplasm.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
            // transform() calls can be chained together
            Protoplasm.use('datepicker')
                .transform('input.datepicker')
                .transform('input.datepicker_es', { 'locale': 'es_AR' });
        </script>
```

Here are the includes I am doing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/datepicker/datepicker.css">
<script src="jquery/protoplasm.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/datepicker/datepicker_src.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/datepicker/datepicker.js"></script>
```

Here is the website I got the datepicker from

```
http://jongsma.org/software/protoplasm/control/datepicker
```

I understand that in their code they do not have the extra src includes but I put these in when I have been trying to get it working. I left them in the code as I think I will need to include them but not 100% as once again js isn't my strongest point because I am new to coding and need to get a lot more learning in js.

If anyone could help me out on how to get this working that would be great and I would appreciate any sort of help that you may be able to provide.

Thanks for reading

Comment: press `F12` on your browser window with the webpage and see if there are any errors in the `Console` tab. If there are, post them here

Comment: Also there's a datepicker provided by jQuery...http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: ^ that's jquery UI. @Luke- show us your work or try replicating this issue on a fiddle. If you can't solve it by then, post the fiddle here.

Comment: I only get one error and that is to do with a twitter button not using css

Comment: here is the fiddle code http://fiddle.jshell.net/PW3cy/    the top javascript has some html in it I believe it is google links but says that it might break the code with html in

Comment: I have found a much better one. An actual jquery one what looks like it is properly done and not something that is going to be a head ache to install. Thank you for the comments. I will post my fix in here as an answer. Once again thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem I was having. What I done was I ended up putting the datepickers into .php file and then included it into my form. I added the js and css includes into this file as well and everything seems to work.

below I have included the link to the timepick I used and also my form, php include and the php what is needed to sort the date before sending to the database. If anyone finds this answer useful then please hit the +1 button.

Below is the link to jquery where I got the date and time picker from. The version I downloaded was 2.1.8 and you should be able to see the download button in right corner and it is a orange button.

```
http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/
```

Below is the .php file. I called it regend.php all of the jquery and css is included in the link above.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/master/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>

<input type="text" value="date/time" id="regend" name="reg_end"/>
<script src="jquery/master/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/master/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>


<script>
$('#regend').datetimepicker();
$('#regend').datetimepicker({value:'date/time',step:10});

</script>
```

Below is the include that I added to my form. I added this within `<form>.......</form>`. I added it to the location I wished it to be displayed.

```
Signup close:<?php include("indexmodules/regend.php");?><br><br>
```

Below is the php code that I used before i sent it to the database to be saved.

```
$reg_end = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST ['reg_end']);
$unix_time = strtotime($reg_end);
$date2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$unix_time);
```

All of the above code should help out any new beginner who is trying to get a date picker working on their website. If I enhance this code I will also post the updated version or version below this.

Thank you to the guys who commented on my original post and I hope this helps people out in the future.